# Basic chat application using java and Atmosphere

Tags: java, websocket, atmosphere

I am trying to get a simple [example](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Getting-Started-with-The-Atmosphere-Framework-and-WebSocket) of a Atmosphere chat program working with Glassfish and Jersery.

So far I have a basic maven webapp archetype with the following structure:

[image: project setup]

The chat resource file is just a simple REST service using the Atmosphere annotations:

```
package core;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import org.atmosphere.annotation.Broadcast;
import org.atmosphere.annotation.Suspend;

@Path("/")
public class ChatResource {

    @Suspend(contentType = "application/json")
    @GET
    public String suspend() {
        return "";
    }

    @Broadcast(writeEntity = false)
    @POST
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response broadcast(Message message) {
        return new Response(message.author, message.message);
    }
}
```

The message and response classes are just simple POJO wrappers. The index.jsp, application.js, jquery.atmosphere.js and jquery.js are copied directly from the example project (found [here](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/tree/master/samples/rest-chat)).

My web.xml is set to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:j2ee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description>AtmosphereServlet</description>
        <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/chat/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When navigating to the page, I receive the following error:

> Sorry, but there's some problem with your socket or the server is down

If I navigate to the path the page is trying to access (http://localhost:8080/.../chat), I get the following message:

> org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereMappingException: No AtmosphereHandler
>   found. Make sure you define it inside META-INF/atmosphere.xml or
>   annotate using @AtmosphereHandlerService

I must be missing a file or setup configuration, but I can't seem to find where (the above message says the atmosphere.xml is missing, but this doesn't appear in the example). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the web socket protocol is not enabled in Glassfish.

You can enable it with the following command:

```
asadmin set configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.websockets-support-enabled=true
```

This is what I needed to get my connection working.

Comment: Could you please post your maven pom ?. I am having  difficulty in compiling this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331792/how-to-to-get-a-atmosphere-rest-chat-sample-to-build-in-standalone-mode